# Given a group $G$ and given any element $g_i \in G$ does $g_i^n \in G$?

Tags: group-theory

Given a finite group $G$ and assuming $G = \{g_0,g_1,g_2,\dots,g_m\}$ for a positive $m$ value. 
If we choose a $g_i$ where $g_i \in G$.
Does the sequence $\{g_i,g_i^2,g_i^3 \dots \ \} \subset G$ due to the fact it is closed under binary operation? How do I guarantee that no element of the sequence will be bigger than $g_m?$ It must have some kind of 'circularity' to make things hold.

Can someone enlight me on how this statement holds(if holds) and why?

Comment: You can see how this *can* happen with an example.  Let $G=\mathbb Z_{24}$ and $g=9$.  $g^2=9+9=18; g^3 =9+18=3; g^4=3+9=12; g^5=12+9=21;g^6=9+21 = 6; g^7=6+9=15; g^8=15+9=0; g^9 = 9 + 0 = 9 =g$.  And we *do*  have some circularity!   ... Now if you think about it.... You will *always* have some circularity because.... well, because there are only finitely far you can go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "due to the fact it is closed under binary operation? "

yes, is binary operation so $g_i^2\in g$ and $g*g_i^2 = g^3\in G$ and so by induction for all powers.

> "How do I guarantee that no element of the sequence will be bigger than gm?"

Because that would be logically impossible.  As $G$ has only $m$ elements and all $g_i^k\in G$ there can only be at most $m$ (or fewer) of these $g_i^k$.

> "It must have some kind of 'circularity' to make things hold."

Yes it must. And it does.

There must be infinitely many $g_i^k = g_i^l =g_i^w=.....$.

You will discover later that if $G$ is finite that there will be some value of $k$ where $g_i^k =e$, the identity element, and that therefore $g_i^{nk + r} = g_i^r$ and thus the infinite repeats.  The smallest value of $k$ so that $g_i^k =e$ is called the *order* of $g_i$.

[I *haven't* proven this is so.  But by the fact that there are infinitely many $n \in \mathbb N$ but only finitely many elements in $G$ there must be some $i,j\in \mathbb N, i < j$ but $g^i = g^j$.  From there we can prove that $e=(g^{-1})^i g^{i} = (g^{-1})^ig^{j} = g^{j-i}$.  So there is a $k:= j-i$ where $g^k = e$.]

......

But note.  If $G$ is infinite then all the $g_i^k$ can be distinct.

And BTW, please to not get confused be the subindexes.  They have *nothing* to do with *anything*.

If I had my way I'd have said the group, $G$,  has $m$ elements and not bother giving them labels until needed.

and the statement about powers of elements, I'd say as this: for any $g\in G$ we have $g^k \in G$.  (Which does mean that the set of $\{g,g^2,g^3,.....\}$ must be finite and the there must be (infinitely many) $i,k \in \mathbb N; i\ne k$ but where $g^i = g^k$.  (In other words "It must have some kind of 'circularity' )

I hope things are clear.

......

points to the OP for the phrase ""It must have some kind of 'circularity' " which is absolutely true.

And thanks to LSpice for telling me not to label the elements of $G$ as $\{e,a,b,c,....,z\}$ which just trades one confusion for another.

Comment: May I propose that we neither label the elements with meaningless indices nor with letters of the alphabet, which restricts us to considering a 26-element group (and also perhaps leads to some worry about that element $e$ being out of order, and also, since $g$ is now a specific element, prevents us from using it as an unbound variable)?

Comment: That is, I think it is more instructive not to say "We have a group $G = \{g_0, g_1, g_2, \dotsc, g_m\}$" nor "We have a group $G = \{e, a, b, c, \dotsc, z\}$", but just "We have a group $G$", and hold off naming *any* of its elements until they are needed.

Comment: Normally I'd agree with you $100\%$.  But in this *one* particular lesson where will find ourselves saying the very basic and true "For ever $g_i$ we must have $g_i^k = g_j$ for some $g_j\in G$" and now the *notation* would be utterly confusing to a student seeing it for the first time.  I didn't *like* $\{e,a,b...z\}$ but it doesn't limit if we state *distinctly* the elements can have *any* variable label we want.... Oh, just read you second comment.  Yes, that *is* better.

Answer (score 4):

This is part of the definition of a binary operation and a group.  The product of any two elements in a group is again an element of that group.

As for being "bigger than $g_m$", that doesn't make any sense.  There is no inherent notion of size in a group, so there is no bigger to speak of.  The indexes you've chosen to use to label your group elements are completely arbitrary and have nothing to do with the size of those elements.

It may help to work out a few examples of small finite groups.  Write down all their elements and work out how to compute products of those elements.

Comment: I think the questioner's worry is:  since I have an infinite list of powers, if I write $g_i^k = g_{n_k}$, then eventually the indices $n_k$ must exceed $m$.  This is not true, and the questioner indicates why:  there will eventually be some 'circularity', whereby $n_k$ equals $n_\ell$ even though $k \ne \ell$.  This is good, and deserves emphasis:  they have just (nearly) re-discovered that every element of a finite group has finite order!

Comment: In particular, I'd suggest looking at a small group like $S_3$ or $S_4$ or possibly the binary quaternion group $Q$ to see how this works in some cases that are a bit more complicated than just $C_n$.

Comment: It's possible that the subindexes are confusing to the OP. (the would be to me).  You are correct that an element being "bigger" than $g_m$ doesn't make sense, but I think it is clear the OP means more elements than just the $m$ listed.  S/he may be making a faulty assumption that $g^1 < g^2 < ....$ which isn't meaningful.  But s/he deserves a *lot* or credit for the logic that every element has only finitely many powers before they must start repeating. (Credit where credit is due.)